# How can I deserialize a json into a hashmap that contains a key and a Object?

Tags: android, json, serialization, hashmap, json-deserialization

This is the form my Json has:

```
{
"records": {
    "fastest": {
        "30": {
            "category": "fastest",
            "timestamp": 1407422694,
            "value": 2,
            "group_id": 30,
            "trip_id": 3429,
            "id": 28247
        },
        "42": {
            "category": "fastest",
            "timestamp": 1423570020,
            "value": -467,
            "group_id": 42,
            "trip_id": 9082,
            "id": 28040
        },
        "43": {
            "category": "fastest",
            "timestamp": 1410960788,
            "value": 16,
            "group_id": 43,
            "trip_id": 5138,
            "id": 28044
        },
        "46": {
            "category": "fastest",
            "timestamp": 1404286123,
            "value": 1609,
            "group_id": 46,
            "trip_id": 2524,
            "id": 28050
        }
    },
    "longest_flight": {
        "category": "longest_flight",
        "timestamp": 1434897403,
        "value": 1242203,
        "group_id": null,
        "trip_id": 12633,
        "id": 27950
    }
}
}
```

I know how to get the longest_flight object. But how can I create the hashmap that contains the list created from the "fastest" json object?

Comment: Imagine engineers would figure this out without father google/stack. If it were you my friend you would be fired. You should consider doing a google search first. Android: Your Question. You're pretty much saying do this for me

Comment: The problem was that the id's are dynamic, getting about 200 values, in the hashmap, like "id" : {object}.
Now I was using GSON, and gson has a way to extract a JSONARRAY or JSONOBJECT. I had an ideea of how to extract the hashmap. BUT, being so that I'm not the first person that does this. I said I will ask, maybe somebody knows a library for this (on ios they have a library for this).
Anyhow, not finding a library, and the examples on google that I found we're not helping, I started and done it my own way. But that threw me back about 2-3 hours. which I hoped wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a function that returns an arraylist, from the JSON (being that the key is also inside the object, and I don't need it for my logic)
Code:

```
 public static ArrayList<Record> sortedRecordsFromJson(String statsJson){
    try{
        Map map = new Gson().fromJson(statsJson, Map.class);
        ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            if(pair != null){
                Log.i("","pair : " + pair.toString());
                String json = pair.getValue().toString().replace(" ", "-");
                json = json.replace(",-", ", ");
                Log.i("","pair json is: " + json);
                JSONObject citiesObj = new JSONObject(json);
                Log.i("","cities obj " + citiesObj.toString());
                if(citiesObj != null){
                    Record tempMap = new Gson().fromJson(citiesObj.toString(), Record.class);
                    records.add(tempMap);
                }
            }
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }
        Log.i("","got here, size:" + records.size());
        return records;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("","exception is: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Calling it like:

```
   ArrayList fastest = Utils.sortedRecordsFromJson(statsJson.getJSONObject("fastest").toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're asking how to get the JSONObject from the URL or how to just retrieve the object once you have the JSONObject already. so here's an answer for both.

This gets a JSONObject from a URL:

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

//attempts to open a connection to the specified url and returns a JSon response object
public JSONObject getResponseObject() {
    try {
        //Use URL connection 
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");


        // attempt the connection
        conn.connect();

        // Get the response code
        responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        // Check the response code, if the HTTP response code is 4nn
        // (Client Error) or 5nn (Server Error), then you may want to
        // read the HttpURLConnection#getErrorStream() to see if the
        // server has sent any useful error information.
        if (responseCode < 400) {

            // Get the response InputStream if all is well
            responseInputStream = conn.getInputStream();

            responseString = getResponseText(responseInputStream);

            try{
                responseObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
            }catch (JSONException et) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            conn.disconnect();


        } else if (responseCode >= 400) {

            // Get the response ErrorStream if we got an error instead
            responseInputStream = conn.getErrorStream();
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 return responseObject;
}
```

You can parse the responseObject like so:

```
JSONObject records = responseObject.getJSONObject("records");
JSONObject longestFlight = records.getJSONObject("longest_flight");
String id = longestFlight.getString("id");
```

To iterate over the keys in a JSON:

I should mention that you'll probably need to do this for each object in your JSON.

```
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
   try {
       Object value = json.get(key);
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       // Something went wrong!
   }
}
```

Comment: I use Volley for networking, you should too, because it's way easier to user. I knew how to retrieve the json Object also.
My problem was I couldn't turn my JSONObject "Records" into a class Record.class, cause of all the dynamic keys (for the hashmap) ,  that I would get.
So I made the class below, which goes through the json, takes only the value of the hashmap, then creates a class, for each value. sets them in an array and then I return the Arraylist of object :)

Comment: Interesting. Have you looked at the [Gson](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) library from Google? It allows a direct from Json to Class serialization that's pretty intuitive to use. I'm not sure how it would handle serializing dynamic JSON objects like you're trying to do, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: I am using Gson, with Volley. BUT Gson allows you to serialize directly from Json to Class a JSONObject or JSONArray, but doesn't work on hashmaps. If you look over the answer I posted below. you see I am using Gson inside the code I made :D

Comment: I dunno, I don't do the shitty JSON, I just get it and need to parse it. This is how it was done for iOS , this is how I need to do it on Android, The annoying part of working with android....

Comment: In that case the Json.keys() method may come in handy. I added it to my answer above. It should let you create a hash map with the values using the get function. It's very similar to what you did, just with less string jiggery-ness.